# Hamburger getting outside of mobile width due to ckeditor form . What to do?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-ckeditor

I am new to django. I am trying to build blog website.
On laptop create new post is perfectly visible like below.
[On laptop create new post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdKmh.jpg)
But when i view it with mobile view hamburger got extended outside the mobile width
[no hamburger visible at first view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnnkW.jpg)
[hamburger visible after dragging page towards right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHTWn.jpg)
i figured out this is due to ckeditor form which i have used for writing 'Text' in form. I don't know what should i do as i tried to set margin but it is only affecting other form fields not the 'Text' one.

Note:[hamburger visible on other pages of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwmge.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one in your `settings.py` file:

```
 CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
     'default': {
         'toolbar': 'full',
         'height': 300,
         'width': '100%',
         'contentsCss': 'img {max-width: 100%;height: auto! important;}',
     },
 }
```

Comment: Yes Jafoor bhai , its working ! You are great ! How can i contact you bro in case of any web dev doubts. I really want to learn web development. Plz ans my doubts whenever you are free bro. I am from India.

Comment: Ok Jafoor Bhai, I have approved your ans. already.

Comment: Actually i have done but they are showing this msg ----Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.